# How to get Video ID from CloudFlare or post it with generated ID?

Tags: go, cloudflare

I upload a video to CloudFlare with Golang and I need to get video ID.

CloudFlare Upload docs: [link](https://developers.cloudflare.com/stream/getting-started/uploading-golang/)

I think there are two ways:
1. Get ID after video will be uploaded
2. Upload video with ID, which I generate on my backend

I have spent several days trying to find some information about it, but I could not

Here is my Golang code for uploading Video file:

```
// get file from request
file, err := c.FormFile("file")
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("get file error: %s", err)
    return c.JSONStatus(http.StatusBadRequest)
}

sourceFile, err := file.Open()
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("open file error: %s", err)
    return c.JSONStatus(http.StatusInternalServerError)
}

fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(sourceFile)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

// Here I generate Video ID (which I save to my DB)
fileName := uuid.New().String()

// Upload to CloudFlare
headers := make(http.Header)
headers.Add("X-Auth-Email", "***")
headers.Add("X-Auth-Key", "***")

config := &tus.Config{
    ChunkSize:           5 * 1024 * 1024,
    Resume:              false,
    OverridePatchMethod: false,
    Store:               nil,
    Header:              headers,
}

client, err := tus.NewClient("https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/"+ accountID +"/media", config) // I have tried to add /id after /media but I got 400 status code
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("create upload client error: %s", err)
    return c.JSONStatus(http.StatusInternalServerError)
}

upload := tus.NewUploadFromBytes(fileBytes)

uploader, err := client.CreateUpload(upload)
if err != nil {
    log.Errorf("create upload error: %s", err)
    return c.JSONStatus(http.StatusInternalServerError)
}
```

Comment: Do you need ID of video or full link is also enough? If link is enough you probably can get this URL via `uploader.Url()` method.

Comment: So I get get video ID by parsing url?

Comment: I think that in this url the last part after `/` is video ID. So url will look like `https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/{accountID}/media/{videoID}` and yes you can probably fetch information via this url.